# I need a test-file with all HTML5 elements

Tags: html, file

I am doing some testing on a new html5-css3 framework and I want to test it against some classless HTML-files to see how my framework behaves.

Does anyone know of one or more static HTML file with all HTML5 tags in various configurations (preferably without classes) that I can use for testing my framework. It would be a big timesaver for me.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have never used it but [<strike>this page</strike>](http://ackernaut.com/space-station/html5-elements/)<sup>*link dead*</sup> [*this* page](https://github.com/cbracco/html5-test-page) appears to be pretty exhaustive and seems to be exactly what you are looking for. You can always check the [HTML5 doctor element index](http://html5doctor.com/element-index/) to make sure that all the HTML5 elements are present in this test page.

Comment: Good file! Thanks.
It is missing inputs of different type, command and menu elements but these are easily added.

Comment: For the inputs, try here: http://robertnyman.com/html5/forms/input-types.html

Comment: The answer is accepted but the question isn't answered as you would expect from the title. It would be nice to have a site with **all** elements.

Comment: The first link's dead :(

Comment: @CarlSmith That is disappointing. This answer should really be updated to include an example page, rather than linking to an external page. For the time being, an alternative page is available at https://github.com/cbracco/html5-test-page.

Answer (score -1):

Use <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl+v</kbd> for !DOCTYPE, a, abbr, acronym, address, applet, area, article, aside, audio, b, base, basefont, bdi, bdo, big, blockquote, body, br, button, canvas, caption, center, cite, code, col, colgroup, command, datalist, dd, del, details, dfn, dir, div, dl, dt, em, embed, fieldset, figcaption, figure, font, footer, form, frame, frameset, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, head, header, hgroup, hr, html, i, iframe, img, input, ins, kbd, keygen, label, legend, li, link, map, mark, menu, meta, meter, nav, noframes, noscript, object, ol, optgroup, option, output, p, param, pre, progress, q, rp, rt, ruby, s, samp, script, section, select, small, source, span, strike, strong, style, sub, summary, sup, table, tbody, td, textarea, tfoot, th, thead, time, title, tr, track, tt, u, ul, var, video, wbr.